# Security implications when storing POST data in PHP session

Tags: php, security, session

I would like to save some POST data in my PHP session, like so.

```
$_SESSION['items'] = $_POST;
```

I plan on carrying this data through a couple more pages before saving it in the database. The type of data is text, so it can be anything, including SQL injection.

I will sanitize the data **before** saving it in my database, but only after it's been saved in the session for a little while.

My question is if saving *UN*sanitized raw POST data in the session presents a security concern, even if it will be sanitized later.

Thanks.

Comment: its fine, its just a string

Comment: If you are correctly using SQL statements, you shouldn't be so worried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's safe to store unsanitized user data in a session, so long as you sanitize it before you use it. The only exception to this I can think of is if you're using a database session handler that expects you to sanitize data before storing it in the session.

With that said, I would argue that there is a security concern here. PHP programmers are wired to look at `$_POST` and think unsafe. The same isn't true (or isn't as true) for `$_SESSION`. You, or someone working with your application, might at some point decide they need to do something with a session variable and assume it has already been sanitized.

In general, I think it is best to sanitize data as soon as you receive it.